# System.Web.Helpers.Crypto - Where's the salt?

Tags: c#, asp.net, cryptography

In the past when dealing with passwords I've always stored a salt and a hashed password separately in my data store. Today I was looking to update some legacy code to use a RFC 2898 hash value. I came across the `Crypto.Hash` methods from `System.Web.Helpers`. It looks like these will do most of the heavy lifting for me. There are `GenerateSalt()`, `HashPassword()`, and `VerifyHashedPassword()` methods. The `HashPassword()` and `VerifyHashedPassword()` methods don't take a salt value. The MSDN documentation for `HashPassword()` method says:

"The format of the generated hash bytestream is {0x00, salt, subkey}, which is base-64 encoded before it is returned."

Do I need to worry about a salt? The documentation seems to say that a salt will be generated automatically and stored in the base-64 encoded value? Is this correct? All I need to store is the string returned from `HashPassword()`?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

## Answer

All passwords need to be *salted* in order to hash them securely. In this case, however, you are correct; `System.Web.Helpers.Crypto` takes care of creating a salt for you. You don't need to create one. It is stored in the string returned by `Crypto.HashPassword()`.

## Example

All you need to do is something like this.

```
using System.Web.Helpers;

public void SavePassword(string unhashedPassword)
{
    string hashedPassword = Crypto.HashPassword(unhashedPassword);
    //Save hashedPassword somewhere that you can retrieve it again.
    //Don't save unhashedPassword! Just let it go.
}

public bool CheckPassword(string unhashedPassword)
{
    string savedHashedPassword = //get hashedPassword from where you saved it

    return Crypto.VerifyHashedPassword(savedHashedPassword, unhashedPassword)
}
```

## More Information

- If you would like to learn more about the `Crypto` class you can view it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.helpers.crypto?view=aspnet-webpages-3.2).
- And [here](http://brockallen.com/2012/10/19/password-management-made-easy-in-asp-net-with-the-crypto-api/) is a good blog on the class and some of the ideas behind it.

Comment: I can't imagine how it creates a salt but you do not store in the database for next verification?

Comment: @LeandroDeMelloFagundes The salt and the Hashed password are both stored in the single string returned by `Crypto.HashPassword`

Comment: @MarkRucker How does one extract the salt from the string returned by HashPassword?

Comment: @stormwild The salt is stored in bytes 1 - 16 of the returned string. Because the .NET string type is UTF-16 there isn't a way to directly access the salt. Instead, you'll need to convert the string into a byte array and then use index lookup to get the salt.

Comment: This is not the intent of the Crypto helper. You are responsible to for concatenating the password with the salt and storing that as the hashed password. The answer below is correct.

Comment: @C-SharpNorris I'm not saying you are wrong but I'm curious what you are basing your claim on. I can't find any documentation of Crypto's intended use anywhere. Also of note, a few years after the below referenced answer the poster changed his answer (http://forums.asp.net/post/5560122.aspx).

Comment: @MarkRucker Perhaps MS didn't give direct guidance here, but there are clear patterns how how you store hashed passwords. There have to be at least 2 fields in the database/store: the hashed password and the salt, not just a hashed password. Getting the salt some way from the hash is not secure or the right approach. The pattern = Crypto.HashPassword(string.Concat(<user defined password>, salt)). See answer below (the BrockAllen portion).

Comment: @C-SharpNorris BrockAllen changes his answer a year later. My link to the blog post above is written by Brock explaining why Crypto.HashPassword() is sufficient. You do need both the salt and the hash but there is no reason why you can't concatenate the two columns into one. This is what the Crypto library does.

Comment: @MarkRucker Man do you know by any chance what hashing algorithm is used in ASP.NET Identity? How can I compare it to the password hashed using Crypto.HashedPassword?

Comment: @JayceeEvangelista That's a question and a half. ASP.NET Identity is a lot of things. My best guess is that you are referring to the UserManager they provide as part of their Identity Framework (which you don't have to use). In that case I'm not sure. I think you'd have to look up the algorithms in the documentation.

Answer (score -2):

Just wanted to share this post:

http://forums.asp.net/t/1842429.aspx?System+Web+Helpers+Crypto+HashPassword

> Hello,
>   I have been looking at the new Crypto HashPassword and VerifyMethod method in System.Web.Helpers.
>   Both methods use a Salt but they do not return the Salt only the Hash.
>   Don't I need the Salt to store it in the database? Am I missing something?
>   Thank you,
>   Miguel

..

> You'd generate the salt when the user creates the account, and then
>   you'd append it to the password before you call HashPassword. You'd
>   then store that salt and the hashed password in your DB. When you
>   validate credentials just read the salt from the DB and appends it to
>   the password from the login before calling VerifyHashedPassword.
>   BrockAllen

..

> Not sure if I understood it ... Because in HashPassword a Salt is
>   generated inside the method:
>
> Miguel

```cs
// Method in Crypto class
public static string HashPassword(string password)
{
    if (password == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("password");
    }

    // Produce a version 0 (see comment above) password hash.
    byte[] salt;
    byte[] subkey;
    using (var deriveBytes = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, SaltSize, PBKDF2IterCount))
    {
        salt = deriveBytes.Salt;
        subkey = deriveBytes.GetBytes(PBKDF2SubkeyLength);
    }

    byte[] outputBytes = new byte[1 + SaltSize + PBKDF2SubkeyLength];
    Buffer.BlockCopy(salt, 0, outputBytes, 1, SaltSize);
    Buffer.BlockCopy(subkey, 0, outputBytes, 1 + SaltSize, PBKDF2SubkeyLength);
    return Convert.ToBase64String(outputBytes);
}
```

..

> BrockAllen
>   Sep 11, 2012 07:50 PM
>
> Yea, ignore that -- it's an internal salt for the Rfc2898DeriveBytes
>   and it's derived from the password so it's not a true salt in the
>   context of storing passwords since it's consistently re-created for
>   the same password. You will want to still do your own salt at the
>   password string level. So something like this:

```cs
public void CreateAccount(string username, string password)
{
    var salt = Crypto.GenerateSalt();
    var saltedPassword = password + salt;
    var hashedPassword = Crypto.HashPassword(saltedPassword);
    CreateAccount(username, salt, hashedPassword);
}

public void Verify(string username, string password)
{
    var salt = GetSaltForUserFromDatabase(username);
    var hashedPassword = GetHashedPasswordForUserFromDatabase(username);
    var saltedPassword = password + salt;
    if (Crypto.VerifyHashedPassword(hashedPassword, saltedPassword))
    {
        // valid password for this username
    }
}
```

This will allow you to store your salt in the database along with the hashed salted password.

Additional info on password hashing with salt in general from this post:
https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm

To Store a Password

1. Generate a long random salt using a CSPRNG.
2. Prepend the salt to the password and hash it with a standard cryptographic hash function such as SHA256.
3. Save both the salt and the hash in the user's database record.

To Validate a Password

1. Retrieve the user's salt and hash from the database.
2. Prepend the salt to the given password and hash it using the same hash function.
3. Compare the hash of the given password with the hash from the database. If they match, the password is correct. Otherwise, the password is incorrect.

Source Code for Crypto class:

http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Helpers/Crypto.cs

Comment: This answer is misleading and outdated. There is no need to manually create your own salt. Brock Allen was incorrect about needing to do that and updated thread later with this comment: BrockAllen "There's no need to manually salt the password -- that is already being done by the Crypto.HashPassword API. See this post:

http://brockallen.com/2012/10/19/password-management-made-easy-in-asp-net-with-the-crypto-api/