# MVC - How to hash and salt

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, hash

I managed to get hash working, but the salt-part is still an issue.. I've been searching and testing examples without success. This is my code with hash:

```
        [Required]
        [StringLength(MAX, MinimumLength = 3, ErrorMessage = "min 3, max 50 letters")]
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public string Salt { get; set; }
```

**Hash password function(without salt):**

```
 public string HashPass(string password) { 

       byte[] encodedPassword = new UTF8Encoding().GetBytes(password);
       byte[] hash = ((HashAlgorithm) CryptoConfig.CreateFromName("MD5")).ComputeHash(encodedPassword);
       string encoded = BitConverter.ToString(hash).Replace("-", string.Empty).ToLower();

          return encoded;//returns hashed version of password
      }
```

**Register:**

```
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Register(User user) {
            if (ModelState.IsValid) {

                        var u = new User {
                            UserName = user.UserName,                               
                            Password = HashPass(user.Password)//calling hash-method
                        };

                        db.Users.Add(u);
                        db.SaveChanges();

                    return RedirectToAction("Login");
                }
            }return View();    
        }
```

**Login:**

```
     public ActionResult Login() {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Login(User u) {
            if (ModelState.IsValid) 
            {
                using (UserEntities db = new UserEntities()) {

                    string readHash = HashPass(u.Password);

                    var v = db.Users.Where(a => a.UserName.Equals(u.UserName) &&
                                              a.Password.Equals(readHash)).FirstOrDefault();
                    if (v != null) {

                        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home"); //after login
                    }
                }
            }return View(u);
        }
```

So far hash work.. But how do I make salt work here?

I would prefer a demonstrate on my code as I find it very hard to understand by words.

I'm using database first.

Comment: There is a good example available [HERE](http://www.obviex.com/samples/hash.aspx)

Comment: [Salted Password Hashing - Doing it Right](https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm)

Comment: This message has been already answered [here.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138429/hash-and-salt-passwords-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Just using a hash function is not sufficient and just adding a salt does little to improve the security. Instead iIterate over an HMAC with a random salt for about a 100ms duration and save the salt with the hash. Use functions such as `PBKDF2`, `password_hash`, `Bcrypt` and similar functions. The point is to make the attacker spend a lot of time finding passwords by brute force with a popular password list.

Answer (score 4):

When it comes to security don't try to reinvent the wheel. Use [Claims](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Claims-based_identity) based authentication.

If you still must manage usernames and passwords use Hash-based message authentication code ([HMAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash-based_message_authentication_code))

I would also recommend investing sometime and reading [Enterprise Security Best Practices](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd277328.aspx). There are already smarter people who solved this problems why reinvent the wheel. And .NET has all the goodies there.

Example below:

```
//--------------------MyHmac.cs-------------------
public static class MyHmac
{
    private const int SaltSize = 32;

    public static byte[] GenerateSalt()
    {
        using (var rng = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider())
        {
            var randomNumber = new byte[SaltSize];

            rng.GetBytes(randomNumber);

            return randomNumber;

        }
    }

    public static byte[] ComputeHMAC_SHA256(byte[] data, byte[] salt)
    {
        using (var hmac = new HMACSHA256(salt))
        {
            return hmac.ComputeHash(data);
        }
    }
}



//-------------------Program.cs---------------------------
string orgMsg = "Original Message";
        string otherMsg = "Other Message";


        Console.WriteLine("HMAC SHA256 Demo in .NET");

        Console.WriteLine("----------------------");
        Console.WriteLine();

        var salt = MyHmac.GenerateSalt();

        var hmac1 = MyHmac.ComputeHMAC_SHA256(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(orgMsg), salt);
        var hmac2 = MyHmac.ComputeHMAC_SHA256(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(otherMsg), salt);


        Console.WriteLine("Original Message Hash:{0}", Convert.ToBase64String(hmac1));
        Console.WriteLine("Other Message Hash:{0}", Convert.ToBase64String(hmac1));
```

NOTE: Salts do not have to be kept secret and can be stored alongside the hash itself. It's to increase security from [rainbow table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table) attack.

Comment: Are you saying that using salt isn't significantly meaningful when using claims based security? The thing you mentioned about not reinventing the wheel sounds like that. Please elaborate?

Comment: I am saying use existing libraries like Identity Server or other .NET solutions. Don't implement your own.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `System.Web.Helpers.Crypto` NuGet package from Microsoft. **It takes care of the salt for you.**

You hash a password like this: `var hash = Crypto.HashPassword("foo");`

You verify a password like this: `var verified = Crypto.VerifyHashedPassword(hash, "foo");`

Comment: Are you saying that salting doesn't need to be handled manually at all in any way when using the helpers mentioned in your answer?

Comment: That should be correct. See the discussion here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17693918/system-web-helpers-crypto-wheres-the-salt

Comment: It's been a few years since that question's been asked and I wonder which of the helpers that are supposedly the best choice for modern .NET Core environments (i.e. 2.x at least, preferably 3.x). I've found [this thing](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System-Web-Helpers.dll/) and [that thing](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebHelpers/). Both seem not to be maintained anymore, though. Which version and what NuGet are you using currently?

Comment: I see that [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/consumer-apis/password-hashing?view=aspnetcore-3.1) provides a how-to on hashing a password but that's nowhere near the *Crypto* class, most seems to be manually managed, in contrary to your statement. It makes me fear that I'm barking up the wrong tree. Please advise.

Comment: We're using the latter (Version 3.2.7), but we're not using .NET Core.

Comment: @KonradViltersten There seems to be a .NET Core compatible alternative now. But I haven't used it, yet. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.passwordhasher-1?view=aspnetcore-6.0